# Extract a set of sequences from a list in python using res not yielding expected result

Tags: python, regex

I have the following list made of character elements in python

```
  LIST1=["AR BR_16_0138244", "AR # BR_16_0138254","AR BR_16_0138264, HHGG AR BR_16_0138264", "AR 
  R_16_01382649" ,"AADSFG AR # R_16_01382679 AR # R_16_01382679" ]
```

In this list, the pattern AR is constant followed by an alphanumeric sequence starting with BR_ or R_. I would like to extract a unique list from the above and the end result should be as folows

```
 ["BR_16_0138244", "BR_16_0138254", "BR_16_0138264", "R_16_01382649", "R_16_01382679"]
```

How do i accomplish this. I have tried the following

```
import re
res = [x for x in LIST1 if re.search("R_", x)] 
print(res)
```

This yields

```
 ['AR BR_16_0138244', 'AR # BR_16_0138254', 'AR BR_16_0138264, HHGG AR BR_16_0138264', 'AR 
 R_16_01382649', 'AADSFG AR # R_16_01382679 AR # R_16_01382679']
```

and not the expected result

I request someone to take a look

Comment: I think you take the whole string if re.search can find a match, but you could take the match instead `(\bB?R_\w+)(?!.*\1)` https://regex101.com/r/Drb365/1

Comment: This returns an empty list am afraid.

Comment: Try this `[sub[sub.index("R_")-1:] for sub in LIST1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the whole match because in the code you check if re.search has a match.

What you can do instead, is print the unique match itself by matching an optional B followed by R_ and 1+ word chars.

Capture the match in group 1, and use a negative lookahead to assert that what is captured does not occur again in the string.

```
(\bB?R_\w+)(?!.*\1)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Drb365/1/) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/4axs7G)

For example

```
import re

LIST1=["AR BR_16_0138244", "AR # BR_16_0138254","AR BR_16_0138264, HHGG AR BR_16_0138264", "AR R_16_01382649" ,"AADSFG AR # R_16_01382679 AR # R_16_01382679" ]

pattern = r"(\bB?R_\w+)(?!.*\1)"
for s in LIST1:
    m = re.search(pattern, s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
BR_16_0138244
BR_16_0138254
BR_16_0138264
R_16_01382649
R_16_01382679
```

---

Another option is to use re.findall to get all the matches, and then at the end convert the result to a set and list to remove the duplicates.

```
import re

LIST1=["AR BR_16_0138244", "AR # BR_16_0138254","AR BR_16_0138264, HHGG AR BR_16_0138264", "AR R_16_01382649" ,"AADSFG AR # R_16_01382679 AR # R_16_01382679" ]

pattern = r"\bB?R_\w+"
result = []
for s in LIST1:
    result += re.findall(pattern, s)

print(list(set(result)))
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/9UxpNu)

Comment: Thank you sir. Will this work regardless of the length of each item in the list and the position of the expected sequence

Comment: @Raghavanvmvs The length of the item does not matter as long as the pattern matches it. The position in the string does not matter, as the first example takes the unique match from the current item in the iteration. The second example takes all the matches, adds it to the result and then turns it into a list with only unique values.